# Previewing SwiftUI toolbars on macOS

Tags: xcode, macos, swiftui, swiftui-previews

Is there any way to preview the toolbar for a macOS SwiftUI app? I can't figure out how to structure my preview to get it to display the toolbar items in a view. It does the right thing when actually running, but not in preview.

I’ve tried putting my preview in a `NavigationStack` and even in a `NavigationSplitView` (which is what the app does). I’ve tried specifying `.previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: "Mac"))` as well. It won’t even show the toolbar in the live preview (where it runs outside of Xcode).